# price() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' while trying to calculate the price in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, save, postman

I am trying to create a case where when I call the order create api, the price will be calculated itself and saved in the database but I am getting this error in the postman.

Error: **price() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self**

My models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)   
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    total_price = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    #billing_details = models.OneToOneField('BillingDetails',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,related_name="order")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email
  
def price(self):
    total_item_price = self.quantity * self.item.varaints.price
    return total_item_price

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    #user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True
    #orderItem_ID = models.UUIDField(max_length=12, editable=False,default=str(uuid.uuid4()))
    orderItem_ID = models.CharField(max_length=12, editable=False, default=id_generator)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True,related_name='order_items')
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    order_variants = models.ForeignKey(Variants, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    total_item_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True,null=True,default=price())

    ORDER_STATUS = (
        ('To_Ship', 'To Ship',),
        ('Shipped', 'Shipped',),
        ('Delivered', 'Delivered',),
        ('Cancelled', 'Cancelled',),
    )
    order_item_status = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=ORDER_STATUS,default='To_Ship')
```

Here quantity field is present in the OrderItem model itself but the price is present in the Variant model which is related to the Product model like this.

**Things I tried:**

1. I tried removing brackets () in price, but got same error.
2. If I tried putting price function inside class model before total_itel_price field, it says self is required inside bracket of price, and if I put self, = is required and I dont know to put in price(self=??)

Other Models:

```
Class Variants(models.Model):
    ...#other fields    
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20,default=500)

Class Product(models.Model):
    ...#other fields
    variants = models.ManyToManyField(Variants,related_name='products')
```

My serializer:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    billing_details = BillingDetailsSerializer()
    order_items = OrderItemSerializer(many=True)
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['id','user','ordered_date','order_status', 'ordered', 'order_items', 'total_price','billing_details']
        # depth = 1   

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        if not user.is_seller:
            order_items = validated_data.pop('order_items')
            billing_details = validated_data.pop('billing_details')
            order = Order.objects.create(user=user,**validated_data)
            BillingDetails.objects.create(user=user,order=order,**billing_details)
            for order_items in order_items:
                OrderItem.objects.create(order=order,**order_items)
            
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("This is not a customer account.Please login as customer.")
```

**Updated Code:**

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):   
    
 #total_item_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True,null=True,default=0) #commented out this field other fields are same as above


order_item_status = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=ORDER_STATUS,default='To_Ship')

@property
def price(self):
    return self.quantity * self.item.varaints.price

class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
    order = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    price = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = ['id','order','orderItem_ID','item','order_variants', 'quantity','order_item_status','price']
        # depth = 1
```

Order Serializer is just like above. It includes OrderItemSerializer as shown:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    billing_details = BillingDetailsSerializer()
    order_items = OrderItemSerializer(many=True)
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['id','user','ordered_date','order_status', 'ordered', 'order_items', 'total_price','billing_details']
```

**Update for Order total_price calculation.**

This is what I did for total_price calculation but I am not getting total_price field in the api response, there is no error though.

```
class Order(models.Model):     
.....#same fields as above

    @property
    def total_order_price(self):
        return sum([_.price for _ in self.order_items_set.all()])
```

I have used price function in the OrderItem model and my instance of OrderItem is order_items. What is the issue??

Comment: Define your price function inside the order class as a class method.

Comment: I have updated my question with things I tried. I have already put the function inside the Model class but it says to pass self from the function call. Also I have to put self=somthing. But I dont know what to put.

Comment: In your question, you have defined the price function outside of the class.

Comment: Yes, but I have tried putting inside the class and got the same error.

Comment: Your `price(self)` method should be inside `OrderItem` class. As the method's outside of a class, it expects the `self` parameter to passed. And also change the parameter `default=price()` of attribute `total_item_price ` inside `OrderItem` class to be `default=price`.

Comment: Define price as property. It should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code finally worked for OrderItem price calculation:

```
class OrderItem(models.Model): 
.....#fields same as above
    #total_item_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True,null=True,default=0)

    ORDER_STATUS = (
        ('To_Ship', 'To Ship',),
        ('Shipped', 'Shipped',),
        ('Delivered', 'Delivered',),
        ('Cancelled', 'Cancelled',),
    )
    order_item_status = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=ORDER_STATUS,default='To_Ship')

    @property
    def price(self):
        total_item_price = self.quantity * self.order_variants.price
        return total_item_price
```

There was a typo in variants. Also, I should be using order_variants instead of item.variants because item has many variants but the user selects only one which has a unique price.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
class Order(models.Model):
    """Stores the details of the order"""

    user: User = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # billing_details = models.OneToOneField('BillingDetails',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,related_name="order")

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.user.email

    @property
    def total_price(self) -> int:
        """
        Dropped the total price field and created it as property
        This is not the best practice, I am leaving that as practice for you :)
        """
        return sum([_.total_item_price for _ in self.orderitem_set.all()])


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    """Order Item stores the details of the each order item"""

    orderItem_ID: str = models.CharField(
        max_length=12, editable=False, default=id_generator
    )
    order: Order = models.ForeignKey(
        Order,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name="order_items",
    )
    item: Product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True
    )
    order_variants: Variants = models.ForeignKey(
        Variants, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True
    )
    quantity: int = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    @property
    def total_item_price(self):
        """
        Calculates total item price for the item
        Here you can also add additional logics such as
        taxes per item etc

        """

        return self.price * self.quantity

    ORDER_STATUS = (
        ("To_Ship", "To Ship"),
        ("Shipped", "Shipped"),
        ("Delivered", "Delivered"),
        ("Cancelled", "Cancelled"),
    )
    order_item_status = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, choices=ORDER_STATUS, default="To_Ship"
    )
```

Comment: Don't you think the `price` method should be inside `OrderItem` class as the `Order` class does not have the attributes `quantity` and `item` which are required in the `price` method.

Comment: Ah. @Kishore, nice catch I didn't went through the code. Let me update the answer.

Comment: Hello @VJMagar I tired your code, but it my post call api, the reuslts I get is price = 0. There is no error though, Order is created. I check the item price, it is 500.

Comment: So, total_item_price dont need to be saved on database?? Different products are from different vendors, so I think I need total_item_price in the future too.

Comment: Also, I saw you removed total_price from Order model as well.

Comment: In the above case, I had assumed that the price is linked to the item, you can modify the price linking from item to item_variant. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230720/discussion-between-saroj-paudel-and-vj-magar).

Comment: I tired your code. I removed the order_item_price but models and as well as from serializers. But now its not showing the price in the results of api call.

Comment: We are required to include the total_price and the total_item_price in respective serializers meta class field attribute. Otherwise those will not part of serializer. Also, I had updated the definition of total item price to calculate the total price using the price property of order item

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230724/discussion-between-sp-django-and-vj-magar).

Comment: Yes I have placed it in serailizers. Can you check my updated code once please?/ @VJMagar

Comment: Hello @VJMagar OrderItem price finally worked. I have put it as an answer. But I am getting same issue for Order total_price calculation. I have put the updated code. Can you check once? I have put it in the serializers too.

Comment: That looks ok to me 

Comment: But I am getting the total_price response in order api call. I tried printing sum([_.price for _ in self.order_items_set.all()]), but no resuts as well. Stuck since morning

Comment: Is price inside sum calling the the price property of OrderItem model??

Comment: yes. its basically adding the total item price of all the items present in the order

Comment: Then,why it isnt in the response of order api??